# Powershell script to run batch on remote server and save StdOut and StdErr to file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've got some problem. I've written script in powershell to run batch file and save stderror and stdout to files (stdout: `stdout.txt`; stderr: `stderr.txt` and merged stdout and stderr: `AllOutput.txt`

`test.ps1:`

```
$allOutput =  & C:\foo.bat 2>&1
$stderr = $allOutput | ?{ $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }
$stdout = $allOutput | ?{ $_ -isnot [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }

Write-Host $allOutput

$allOutput | Out-File AllOutput.txt
$stdout | Out-File StdOut.txt
$stderr | Out-File StdErr.txt
```

The `foo.bat` file execute some code and bar.bat script:

```
dir
echo test
c:\bar.bat
echo endFoo
```

The `bar.bat` file execute this exaple code:

```
echo test
cd DDDDDD #not exists to get error
cd EEEEEE #not exists to get error
echo endBar
```

When I run test.ps1 directly on server I get `AllOutput.txt` with proper order - when on stderr is an error I get it after command. But when I start it on remote server by `Invoke-Command -computerName serverName -File C:\test.ps1` or by `Invoke-Command -computerName serverNAme -File \\serverPath\test3.ps1` I get output in wrong order - sometimes two errors from stderr in a row, sometime at the end of the file. 
How can I execute it or rewrite in right way?

Comment: PowerShell doesn't guarantee message order across streams.

Comment: Ok I correct scripts with your instructions, but it still doesn't work correctly.